# expression engine sql query limit entries

Tags: sql, expressionengine

Hi I'm not really too familiar with SQL queries using EE but I think that is what I need here. Any advice would be appreciated. 
I'm basically trying to create a typical group gallery homepage that links to each members gallery - but I'm not sure how to limit it to just 1 link per author rather than all channel entries.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="portfolios" author_id="not 1"}
<a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}"><img src="{avatar_url}" /></a><br>
<a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}">{author}</a><br>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  Be sure to replace `t.channel_id = 1` with the actual channel_id of your portfolios channel.

What this will do is list all of the members who have posted entries in that channel. Note that because we're doing an SQL query, `{avatar_url}` isn't prepared, so we just cheat and hardcode the path to the **avatars** folder.

```
{exp:query sql="
    SELECT m.member_id, m.username, m.screen_name, m.avatar_filename
    FROM exp_members m
    LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles t
    ON t.author_id = m.member_id
    WHERE t.channel_id = 1
    GROUP BY m.member_id
    ORDER BY m.screen_name ASC
"}
        <a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}"><img src="/images/avatars/{avatar_filename}" /></a><br>
        <a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}">{screen_name}</a><br>
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: thanks D-Rock- will check this out now - can I ask to help me understand, what  m means on the line FROM exp_members m? and m. Also t and t.

Comment: Sure Mark - adding any letter or word directly following a `FROM table_name` statement creates an alias or reference for that table. It helps you write cleaner SQL when referring to columns. So `m.member_id` refers to the `member_id` column in the `exp_members` table, `t.channel_id` refers to the `channel_id` column in the `exp_channel_titles` table, etc.

Comment: I couldn't get what you posted to work but sort of have this working `{exp:query sql="SELECT member_id, username, screen_name, avatar_filename
FROM exp_members WHERE group_id = '5' ORDER BY username ASC

"}
<a href="{path=portfolios/gallery2/{username}}"><img src="http://localhost:8888/igi/images/avatars/{avatar_filename}" /></a><br>
<a href="{path=portfolios/gallery2/{username}}">{username}</a><br>
{/exp:query}`

Comment: but rather than ordering by {username}, I’d like to order by a member field I created called {surname}
- which is m_field_id_2 in exp_member_data  - any idea how I would do that? 
I tried to use JOIN but it created an error. Is JOIN like saying ‘and’ ? or is there something else I should use?
group_id = ‘5’ is my members group.

Also is there a way to not have to hardcode the link to an avatar filename? how would I allow the placement of {path}?

Comment: A LEFT JOIN is establishing an optional relationship between two or more tables in a query. Try this:`SELECT m.member_id, m.username, m.screen_name, m.avatar_filename
 FROM exp_members m
 LEFT JOIN exp_member_data d
 ON m.member_id = d.member_id
 WHERE m.group_id = '5'
 ORDER BY d.m_field_id_2 ASC`.

Comment: The URL to your avatar director is stored in your site preferences, and it has no global variable. But you could use [this add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/config-variables) to grab it (`{exp:config:vars value="avatar_url"}`).

Comment: thanks a billion derek -seems to have done the trick. So it's the ON that says what you want to organise by?

Comment: Nope, ORDER BY does that. Feel free to accept the answer above.  :)